# Flattening Young Tableaux

Tags: representation-theory, integer-partitions, symmetric-groups, symmetric-polynomials, young-tableaux

Let $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_k)$ be a partition with $|\lambda|=n$ and $\lambda_1\geq \lambda_2\geq\cdots\geq \lambda_k$. For any Standard Young Tableaux (SYT) $T$ of shape $\lambda$, define the "flattened tableaux" by deleting the first row $\lambda_1$, and then relabeling all entries in the tableaux with respect to their relative order, thus giving a SYT  $T'$ of shape $\lambda':=(\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n)$ and $|\lambda'|=n-\lambda_1$. For example, if $\lambda=(4,3,2,1,1)$ with $|\lambda|=10$, then $\lambda'=(3,2,1,1)$. An as an example, take

$T=$
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 3 & 5 & 6\\
2 & 4 & 7 & \ \\
8 & 11 & \ & \ \\
9 & \ & \ & \ \\
10 & \ & \ &\ 
\end{array}

Then,

$T'=$
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & 3 & \ \\
4 & 7 & \ & \ \\
5 & \ & \ & \ \\
6 & \ & \ &\ 
\end{array}

Does this operation have a common name in literature? Has it been studied before? As a map, the flattening operation $\phi: SYT(\lambda)\rightarrow SYT(\lambda')$ is clearly a surjection (and not a bijection). On the other hand, are there specific $\lambda$ for which $\phi$ is uniform in $SYT(T')$? In other words, $|\{T: \ \phi(T)=T'\}|$ is the same for all $T'$?

Comment: Why is this map an injection? In your example, swapping 6 with 7 gives the same SYT after flattening.

Comment: @siddharth Venkatesh: meant to say surjection, pardon!

Answer (score 1):

For any partition $(n)$ or $(k,1^{n-k})$ , the resulting tableaux are respectively empty or a vertical one-column tableau with entries $1,2,...,n-k$.
But for any partition $(k,2,1,1,..,1)$ with $n-k-2$ '$1$'s, the beheaded tableau can be either
$((1,2),(3),..,(n-k-1))$ or $((1,3),(2),..,(n-k-1))$
depending on $T$. So, beyond these special partitions $(n)$ and $(k,1^n-k)$ there can be no such cases.

Comment: I don't understand the solution

Comment: I think he's answering the last question of OP with "no" by showing $T'$ with differing numbers of pre-images.  In any case, "beheaded tableau" is great!